# Which of the following when performing a statistical test is NOT a Random Variable?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value, random-variable, statistical-power

For a test for my stats class, we were asked, 
"When performing a statistical test on a sample, which of the following is NOT a random variable?"

A) The Test Statistic
B) the p-value
C) The power of the test
D) The range of the variable in the sample
E) the 95% confidence interval

I know that functions of random variables are also random variables, so I said that the Power of the Test isn't a random variable

Answer (score 2):

Without answering the question directly (since being in a class requires some thought on your part ;)), one of these can be calculated at the design (planning) stage before the data is collected for testing, so you essentially answered the question already.